# Java/ Sudoku algorithm/ JPanel/ JButtons

Tags: java, algorithm, swing, random, sudoku

I am making a sudoku-style program with JPanel and the program must a legal starting position of the game, the game has to start with 3 to 7 (random) numbers already inserted in the panel in random positions (from 1 to 5).
I have a 5x5 grid with 25 JButtons, I have my random numbers and my random locations of these numbers, except I also have to follow the rules of the game which state that no number can repeat itself in its row and column.
I know I have to select each button (the number that is on the button) and go through the row and column and check if there is a repetition, if there is go back and change number, but I was unable to do so with the many codes I've tried.

```
public class Sudoku implements ActionListener {
    JButton[][] gumbi = new JButton[5][5];

    public Sudoku() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(500, 500);

        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(5, 5));

        Random st = new Random();
        int stevila = st.nextInt(5) + 4;  
            // initial random number to be inserted

        int counter = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {

                Random flag = new Random();
                int f = flag.nextInt(2);            
                            // random location of number

                Random rnd = new Random();
                int r = rnd.nextInt(5) + 1;         
                            // random number, range 1-5

                if (counter < stevila && f == 0) {
                    gumbi[i][j] = new JButton("0");
                } else if (counter < stevila && f == 1) {
                    gumbi[i][j] = new JButton(Integer.toString(r));
                    counter++;
                    gumbi[i][j].setEnabled(false);
                } else {
                    gumbi[i][j] = new JButton("0");
                }

                gumbi[i][j].addActionListener(this);
                panel.add(gumbi[i][j]);
            }
        }

        frame.add(panel);

        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
```

I have to insert something resembling this (recursive or otherwise) to check if there are repetitions in rows and columns.

```
public boolean checkRow(int row, String num) {

        for (int col = 0; col < 5; col++)
            if (gumbi[row][col].getText() == num)
                return false;

        return true;
    }

public boolean checkCol( int col, String num ) {

          for( int row = 0; row < 5; row++ )
             if(gumbi[row][col].getText() == num)
                return false ;

          return true ;
    }
```

It's a whole mess with JPanel, as the buttons contain Strings and not ints (I have to use `JButton.getText` and then convert it to int with `Integer.toString`) and it's just... bad.

Comment: First off you should separate out your code logic from your GUI, and test each in isolation. Your current problem is a logic problem and should be figured out without a GUI.

Comment: Are there any other constraints on the starting configuration, i.e. do you want it to be solvable or to have a unique solution?

Comment: I've been trying to figure this out for quite some time now and my logic has... given up.

Comment: @Henry it has to be legal/ solvable

Comment: `"...and my logic has... given up."` -- Don't give up but continue to attack from another angle. Try to figure out how to solve this on paper without using a computer, and then try to code that logic.

Comment: Firstly you should try to implement a solver, without thinking about the GUI. Then when its done develop the GUI. I also have a Sudoku java app I coded on my HD, and can post it if you are interested.

Comment: legal and solvable is not the same. For instance on a 3x3 board an initial configuration 1 2 x / 2 1 x / x x x is legal but not solvable.

Comment: @Henry thank you for the clarification. It has to be solvable

Comment: @ExtremeCoders do you mean a game solver? if that is what you mean - I need to create just the starting point of the game, solver is... optional.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code snippet will check whether placing a particular number at a particular position is valid or not.

`board` is a 2d `9 x 9` array representing the sudoku game board.
An empty cell i.e. where you have not yet put any number would contain zero.

`row` and `col` are the rwo and column locations of the number `num` you want to place

```
boolean isValidMove(int num, int row, int col)
{
    //1. Check whether the horizontal run contains the number
    for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
        if (board[row][i] == num) return false;

    //2. Check whether the vertical run contains the number
    for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
        if (board[i][col] == num) return false;

    //3. Check whether the 3x3 grid contains the number
    int starting_row = row / 3;
    int starting_col = col / 3;

    for (int i = starting_row * 3; i < starting_row * 3 + 3; i++)
        for (int j = starting_col * 3; j < starting_col * 3 + 3; j++)
            if (board[i][j] == num) return false;

    return true;
}
```

What you can do is implement a recursive backtracking algorithm that tries all possible combinations for a cell (namely 1...9). If a number can be put in that cell proceed to the next one. If not discard the contents of the current cell and move back to the previous one to place the next valid number.

Comment: but that's exactly what I wrote (minus the 3*3 grid which I do not need), and I understand this code, the problem is I don't know how to implement it in the previous code.

Comment: @user2974951 You are developing the whole logic on the UI side. Use a separate `int` array which you would be filling with the numbers. Once that is complete parse the array and build the gui out of it.

Comment: You may be wasting your breath, Extreme. I've been trying to get @user2974951 to do this, but to no avail.

Comment: that makes sense... but easier said than done, a lot could go wrong during that process... things get lost, things pop out of nowhere... if you know what I mean.

Comment: @user2974951 To achieve something requires you to put your efforts and without it you get nothing. You may be failing in your efforts but with repeated efforts you achieve what you want. Barriers always lie in the path of success.